# Get curvature turning points for Linestring geometry

Tags: python, geometry, shapely

I want to count the number of curves a road has, which is represented by a Linestring in my data.

So as an example lets say I have an arbitrary shapely.geometry Linestring like the following, how do I get the turning points (5 in this example)?

For clearity I mean the curvature not the peaks/valleys.

[image]

Sample code:

```
from shapely.geometry import LineString
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# let's use a sine curve as our example line
x = np.arange(0, 6 * np.pi, 0.5)
y = np.sin(x)
xy = list(zip(x, y))
line = LineString(xy)
plt.plot(*line.xy)
plt.show()
```

I tried to iterate all points of the Linestring and detect if y is increasing or decreasing, but this approach will fail if the Linestring is rotated by 90° for example.

Comment: How do you define a curve in the road? For example something like "If the road direction change more than X degrees over Y meters"?

Comment: @BERA Thanks for your question, I haven't thought about that. As a baseline I would have defined it like if it was a function, I would use the point where the second derivative is changing its sign. But after your question it became clear to me that the road could also have a lot of right curves separated by straight segements. So an approach which finds curves by change of curvature (left/right switches) and/or by a certain degree would be much appreciated. For the second approach, I could get the triangle angle and compare it to the length?